# $ \lim_{a\to 0^{+}} \int_0^{\infty} \cosh^n{\theta}e^{-a\cosh{(\theta)}}d\theta$ with $n$ a positive integer

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

I am sure that $$\lim_{a\to 0^{+}} \int_0^{\infty} \cosh^n{(\theta)}e^{-a\cosh{\theta}}d\theta,$$ with $n$ a positive integer, diverges; but I don't know how to demonstrate this affirmation. I tried to bound the integral, but nothing happens. Any help?

Comment: We can apply the monotone convergence theorem to push the limit inside. A more interesting question will be to figure out the speed of divergence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very smart, just using the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition of limits.
For any $A>0$ and any $\delta>a$, 
$$\begin{split}
\int_0^{+\infty} \cosh^n{(\theta)}e^{-a\cosh{\theta}}d\theta &\geq \int_0^{A} \cosh^n{(\theta)}e^{-\delta\cosh{\theta}}d\theta\\
&\geq e^{-\delta\cosh{A}}\int_0^{A} \cosh^n{(\theta)}d\theta\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{(1)}
\end{split}$$
Let $M>0$. There exists $A>0$ such that $$\int_0^{A} \cosh^n{(\theta)}d\theta\geq 2M\tag{2}$$
Now, pick $\delta \leq \frac{\ln 2}{\cosh A}$. Then
$$e^{-\delta\cosh{A}}\geq\frac 1 2 \tag{3}$$
Combining (1), (2) and (3), we see that for all $0\leq a \leq \delta$, 
$$\int_0^{+\infty} \cosh^n{(\theta)}e^{-a\cosh{\theta}}d\theta\geq M$$
So $$\lim_{a\rightarrow0^+}\int_0^{+\infty} \cosh^n{(\theta)}e^{-a\cosh{\theta}}d\theta=+\infty$$